# Best way to process and remove query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

I have two fully functional pages that perform different tasks in an asset management system. On one, the page may display a list of assets with a serial number using a gridview. In that view, I want the serial number to be clickable, and open the other page that actually displays specific asset info. 
I have figured out how to make the link clickable, and have it open the other page passing the serial number as a querystring. 
The problem is when the other page loads. I only want it to process that serial number once-After it is processed, it needs to go back to using the input box on the page for the serial to display. 
So far, I got the page to read the query string, save it as a session variable, and then redirect back to itself without the querystring. The problem is on the redirect, it doesn't seem to re-process the Page_Load event, and read the session variable it set before the redirect. I know it set it because if I hit refesh, it works like a charm, and shows the data for that serial number. But why do I have to hit refesh?
 My Page_Load event calls these two in order. The First copies the querystring to a session, and redirects. The second processes the session variable, and runs the same event handler as the Search Button.

```
    protected void GetSearchQueryString(object sender, EventArgs e)        
    {
        String s = Request.QueryString["SN"];

        if (s != null && s.Length > 0)
        {
            Session["SN"] = s;              
            Response.Redirect("/AssetManagement.aspx");
        }

    }
    protected void GetSearchSessionVar(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (Session["SN"] != null)
            {
                string sessionVal = Session["SN"].ToString();
                AssetSearchTextBox.Text = sessionVal; //setting serial number
                Session.Remove("SN");

                AssetSearchButton_Click(sender, e); //Running asset search
            }            
    }
```

//#####################################################
This is the working code I built inspired by the comment by rs and answer by mashupweb. Checking for postback, and just leaving it as a querystring works. I hate the ugly url, but I can deal with that!

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
            String s = Request.QueryString["SN"];
            if (s != null && s.Length > 0)
            {
                AssetSearchTextBox.Text = s;
                AssetSearchButton_Click(sender, e);
            }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Can you post your `page_load` code? Why do you want to redirect, you can use same request and in `page_load` if request is not `postback` set value from `querystring` to `textbox` and if it is `postback` read value from `textbox`

Comment: I think this will work- I figured I was doing it the hard way. I would still like to know why it wasn't working the way I tried- but thanks!

Comment: Check for postback works- it leaves an ugly url, but it does work: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                String s = Request.QueryString["SN"];

                if (s != null && s.Length > 0)
                {
                    AssetSearchTextBox.Text = s;
                    AssetSearchButton_Click(sender, e);
                }
            }
        }

Comment: post your comment as answer and accept that as answer, so that others will know that this question is already answered.

Answer (score 0):

You're only setting the Session variable if the query string is not null, whereas I think you want it to be cleared if there is no query string.

Try something like this:

```
Session["SN"] = s;  

if (s != null && s.Length > 0)
        {           
            Response.Redirect("/AssetManagement.aspx");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be easier if you can avoid using Sessions unless you really need to, and rely plainly on querystrings.

```
protected void GetSearchQueryString(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{
    String s = Request.QueryString["SN"];

    if (s != null && s.Length > 0)
    {            
        Response.Redirect("/AssetManagement.aspx");
    }

}

protected void GetSearchSessionVar(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (Request.QueryString["SN"] != null)
        {
            string sessionVal = Request.QueryString["SN"].ToString();
            AssetSearchTextBox.Text = sessionVal; //setting serial number

            AssetSearchButton_Click(sender, e); //Running asset search
        }            
}
```

Comment: Then 2nd method will not display text after redirect from first method.

Comment: I see. If it is an ASP.NET page, you can place the contents of the second method in a if (!IsPostBack) method on the page load if the redirect goes back on itself on the same page.